# Uninitialized constant #{MIGRATION_NAME}::#{TABLE_NAME} when running migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration, rake

I have a Rails migration that creates some entries into my table. This table has been created in previous migration. Then, table is existing, for sure.

However, when I am running it, I get this error:

`uninitialized constant AddInitialStates::State`

Here is a sample of my migration:

```
class AddInitialStates < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    State.create :short_name => 'AL', :long_name => 'Alabama'
    State.create :short_name => 'AK', :long_name => 'Alaska'

    # ... other create requests
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is quite simple actually. When running `rake db:migrate`, migration tool expects models to exist. Therefore, here, we get a `uninitialized constant` error. Migration tool is searching a `State` model and will use it to call `create` method.

Then, there are several ways to fix this issue. Most simple is to create missing models.

Otherwise, if you do not want to create them, here is a simple fix. You might need it if you are running transitional migrations to end in right schema version.

For each faulty migration, insert this code within it:

```
class MyMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def MyTable < ActiveRecord::Base; end

  def change
    # Your migration
  end
end
```

These solutions work for every similar solution where a model/entity/table is not found by Rake.

By the way, you should avoid these create requests. Use `seeds.rb` file instead.